# If statement in OrderBy method over Where method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wrote some code below:

```
public IEnumerable<Photo> GetPhotos(int page, int pageSize, string userId = null, OrderBy orderBy = OrderBy.TimeOfCreation)
{
   var c = Database.Set<Photo>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId);
   c = orderBy == OrderBy.TimeOfCreation ? 
       c.OrderBy(p => p.TimeOfCreation).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize) : 
       c.OrderBy(p => p.AverageRaiting).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
   return c
}
```

Is it possible to do it all in one statement and to get rid of the repetitious code?

Comment: When you say *recurring* code, do you mean *repetitious* code?

Comment: @dotctor Exactly! Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign `OrderBy` result back to the same variable:

```
var c = Database.Set<Photo>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId);
c = orderBy == OrderBy.TimeOfCreation 
                      ? c.OrderBy(p => p.TimeOfCreation)
                      : c.OrderBy(p => p.AverageRaiting);

return c.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the condition inside `OrderBy`:

```
var c = Database.Set<Photo>().
    Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId).
    OrderBy(p => orderBy == OrderBy.TimeOfCreation ? p.TimeOfCreation : DateTime.Now).
    ThenBy(p => orderBy == OrderBy.AverageRaiting ? p.AverageRaiting : 0.0).
    Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

return c
```

Comment: Are you sure Linq to Entities will be able to handle it?

Comment: @haim770 That is way I'm asking. It doesn't works if move the condition inside.

Comment: @haim770, yes it does. I have checked.

Comment: @dotctor userId the simple string type. Why not? I get this value from method parameter.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri IDE said "There is no implicit conversion between double and System.DateTime

Comment: There is no ThenBy method avaliable.
What do u think about this: .OrderBy(p => orderBy == OrderBy.TimeOfCreation ? p.TimeOfCreation.Ticks : p.AverageRaiting)

Comment: @user3818229, what do you mean by `not available`? It works for me and it is available.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I mean I don't have this method. Idk why.